# Paging results in my plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm making a plugin that shows a log of certain user actions.

The issue is that I need to add pagination to show only 5 results per page and not how to paginate_links() function.

This is the code I have (there I need to add paging)):

```
$mylink = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_points");

foreach ($milink as $mostrar) 
{

<tr>

echo"<td>".$mostrar->punto_user_ID."</td>
<td>".$mostrar->punto_nombre."</td>
<td>".number_format($mostrar->punto_canjeados, 0, ',', '.')."</td>
<td>".cambiarFormatoFecha($mostrar->punto_fecha)."</td>";

}
echo"</tr>
</tbody>
</table>";
```

Please anyone who can help with the code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick solution that could work

functions used

ceil:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php

wpdb->prepare 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

paginate links
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

```
$per_page = 5;
$page = intval(get_query_var('page')); // cast to int to be on the safe side
$total_pages = ceil($wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_points") / $per_page);  


//use $wpdb->prepare to help against sql injection
$sql  = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_points LIMIT %d, %d", $page * $per_page, $per_page);


// your processing here 

$mylink = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
//...

// here's the helper no magick here, straight from docs
$big=999999999; // dummy used by 'base' below

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?page=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, $page ),
    'total' => $total_pages,
) );
```

Comment: Thank you! I served your help, but now I have another problem with your code. Maybe you can help me, this is the link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727000/i-can-not-paginate-my-plugin)

Comment: when you hover on the link do you see the ?page= changing

Comment: Edited the above answer: missing $ in $wp->prepare caused ($page*$per_page) to always be zero

Answer (score 0):

best to look at [wp_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) ('Pagination Parameters' is somewhere halfway down the page)
use something like:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=5' );
```