# I can not paginate my plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have a code of a plugin I made, which shows a custom table and I need to add paging.

This code does appear pagination and results, but does not work when clicking on the following pages (1, 2, 3 ... etc) but shows the same.

This is my code:

```
$per_page = 3;
$page = intval(get_query_var('page')); // cast to int to be on the safe side
$total_pages = ceil($wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_puntos_log") / $per_page);  


//use $wpdb->prepare to help against sql injection
$sql  = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_puntos_log LIMIT %d, %d", $page * per_page, $per_page);

$mylink = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

foreach ($mylink as $mostrar) 
{

echo"
        <tr>
            <td>".$mostrar->punto_user_ID."</td>
            <td>".$mostrar->punto_nombre."</td>
            <td>".number_format($mostrar->punto_canjeados, 0, ',', '.')."</td>
            <td>".cambiarFormatoFecha($mostrar->punto_fecha)."</td>";

}

echo"       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>";

$big=999999999; // dummy used by 'base' below

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?page=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, $page ),
    'total' => $total_pages,
) );
```

Took a long time trying and not working. I appreciate your help.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: (
I found the problem in the original answer i was missing $ sign

```
$sql  = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_puntos_log LIMIT %d, %d", $page * per_page, $per_page);
```

should be:

```
$sql  = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_puntos_log LIMIT %d, %d", $page * $per_page, $per_page);
```

Comment: It does not work. This was now and still the same: `$per_page = 3;
$page = intval(get_query_var('page')); // cast to int to be on the safe side
$total_pages = ceil($wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_puntos_log") / $per_page);  


//use $wpdb->prepare to help against sql injection
$next_page = $page+1; 

$sql=$wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_puntos_log LIMIT %d, %d", $page * per_page, $next_page*$per_page);`

Comment: i'll get you the correct version soon, just need to actually run this code I wrote from memory

Comment: Still not working! : (When I move to page 2 or 3, still shows the same from page 1 and also marks the current page (still staying on page 1). URL in the navigation bar is: `options-general.php?page=ver_puntos.php&paged=2`

Comment: weird, works here. Try one more thing. Change the line
$page = get_query_var("page") to get_query_var("paged")

Comment: if you still need help post your code somewhere and provide a link

Comment: Ok, please chek: [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/44938577/ver_puntos.php) THANKS!! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Pagination */

function pag_test() {
global $wpdb;
echo "<h1> Custom Pagination Example </h1>";
$per_page = 3;
$page = intval($_GET['paged']); // cast to int to be on the safe side
$total_pages = floor($wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_options") / $per_page);  


//use $wpdb->prepare to help against sql injection
$sql  = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_options LIMIT %d, %d", max($page-1, 0) * $per_page, $per_page);

$mylink = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
?> <table> 
<thead>
<tr>
<th> Option </th>
<th> Value </th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($mylink as $mostrar) 
{

echo"
        <tr>
            <td>".$mostrar->option_name."</td>
            <td>".$mostrar->option_value."</td>
";}

echo"       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>";


$big=999999999; // dummy used by 'base' below

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?page=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, $page ),
    'total' => $total_pages,
) );


}
function pag_addmenu() {
add_menu_page('Pagination', 'pagination', 'manage_options', 'pgtest', pag_test);
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'pag_addmenu');
?>
```

Comment: here's a working example. I've used the wp_options table because I don't have your data. The key was to use $page = $_GET['paged'] rather than get_query_var. I also noticed a small bug in the code where the page would be 1 and you wouldn't see the first set of data this is tested and 100% working

Comment: Perfect! The paging works! :)

The only problem is it is showing less corresponding results. There are 8 entries in the database and if I choose to show 3 results per page, only shows 6 results (2 pages) and should show 3 pages: The first with 3 results, the second with 3 results, and the third with 2 results.

I greatly appreciate your help and your time!

Comment: The problem is with $total_pages
 8 / 3 = 2.66 floor(2.66) = 2

You may want to change the floor (which rounds down) to a ceil that way it will round up. It  may give you an extra empty page in some cases